# Model::all() Does not work in Laravel - other queries do

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and I inherited a project that I needed to put live on a different server. To be clear I didn't write this app nor am I a Laravel expert.

That being said, the app does seem fairly solidly written and I am impressed with the framework. The last PHP framework I used was Cake which seemed like a clunky clone of an older version of Rails, this seems much nicer - but I digress.

In any event. One of the views kept rendering a blank page on the new server. I commented out line after line of code until I t started working again. The culprit was this line:

```
$leads = Lead::all()->count();
```

When I commented it out and replaced the prospects variable with an integer the page loaded.

I fixed the issue by using this instead:

```
DB::table('leads')->count()
```

Now it works fine.

I am still puzzled however why this works on the old server (which, BTW age wise is much newer) but not this one.

I don't have the exact specs on the old server but the server I moved it to is an **ubuntu box running php 5.4.12**

MySQL is externally hosted, both instances of the website connect to it.

The Lead model looks like this:

```
    <?php

    class Lead extends Eloquent {

        protected $guarded = array();


        public function results()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Result');
        }

        public function items()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Item');
        }

    }

?>
```

Just to repeat the ::all() code I am showing runs without error on another server instance, just not on the newer setup.

Thanks!

Comment: Were any errors outputed to app/storage/logs/laravel.log?

Comment: No, I looked in apache and in the Laravel log they didn't tell me anything. I also put the site in debug mode.

Comment: Have you tried this?
$leads = Lead::count();

Comment: Hi Anindya, no the fix I used worked fine. I am mostly perplexed about the :all() not working in case it is indicative of some larger environment issue,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd narrow down the problem and come back with a bit more information -- i.e. step one is to define what you mean by not working.

Does `$leads = Lead::all()->count()` actually return a value, but it's something about this value that makes another part of your application break?  Or is it the calling of `$leads = Lead::all()->count()` that breaks things?

Your description of the error

> One of the views kept rendering a blank page on the new server

Makes this sound like a PHP error.  Since Laravel should throw its own error either (either a generic error page, or a Whoops error if debug mode is on), it sounds like you're dealing with the sort of problem Laravel's error handler can't catch.

You need to get your PHP error logging setup correctly.  PHP usually logs to a custom error file, or the apache/web-server log.  This can be notoriously difficult to get setup -- I'd start with a stand alone PHP page with an obvious error

```
<?php
//no ending ; to create a parse error
$test = 1+1
```

And use that to figure out how/where generic PHP errors get logged.  Once you've done that, you'll be able to see specifically what's crashing PHP/Laravel when you call.  Also, dropping a `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` right in front of your janky line of code is sometimes enough to get PHP to spit out the error to the browser.

All that said, the call to `all` in `Lead::all()->count()` will actually load an entire collection object (memory hungry), and then count it.  The call to `DB::table('leads')->count()` should use a simple SQL count(*).  That, plus the PHP error (vs. Laravel) would point me towards your PHP [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) being lower on the new server, and/or the older version of PHP having less efficient object handling that consumes more memory.

Comment: One further comment, the `view` may be rendering as a blank page if there's nothing on it. Example, if you pass an object and then call `$object->column` and that column doesn't exist, it won't be an error, simply nothing will show up.

Comment: Thanks. I think the memory limit may be the cause. I'll take a look in the morning. I was under the assumption that setting debug=true in laravel overrode the ini settings so errors would be displayed, I will force them on.

Comment: @picus Setting debug to true configures Laravel to use the full Whoops error handler.  PHP's internal `display_errors` ini is still set to false, but Laravel uses the full stack trace Whoops rendering.  More here, if you're interesting in digging into it http://alanstorm.com/laravel_error_handler

Comment: thanks, it was a memory limit error. Maybe the app needs a bit of refactoring after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on the version of laravel you are using, if its the new one, 5.0,

> $leads= User::where('votes', '>', 100)->get();
>
> $count = $leads->count();

something like this would definitely work.